# Need Scroller with both autoplay and manual scrolling functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a scroller which auto scrolls to the end and stops and switches to manual navigation.  I tried googling, there are thousands of scrollers but I need one with both autoplay and manual scroll functionality. Where user can also switch to manual scroll with a single click while it is auto scrolling, something like [this](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/).

But it must stop auto scrolling  when it has reached end and then switch to manual scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery Easy Slider 1.7](http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/) ([Demo here](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/02.html)) has both manual scrolling and automatic scrolling, which automatically turns off as soon as the user clicks on the slider. It's also really easy to customize and extend - and I've done so in a few past projects.

As for the autoscrolling to stop at the last slide, you could manually add the functionality using a timer that turns off autoscrolling after all the slides are done. Or you could play with it and just add an event that gets fired whenever the last slide is reached.

### Edit:

Using [SmoothDivScroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) is even better, because it allows the user (you) to add a number of [callbacks](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/callbacks.html). So you can just turn off autosliding when the last slide is reached:

```
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingRightLimitReached: function(eventObj, data) {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("option","autoScrollingMode","");

    }
});
```

### Edit 2:

Sadly, it seems that callbacks not working are a [known issue on their bugtracker](https://github.com/tkahn/Smooth-Div-Scroll/issues/46). You could try and contact the creator of the script and see whether he's planning on fixing them.

Comment: I have changed the link i gave in the question, please check it. The example i have given is almost perfect except that i want it to stop auto scrolling once it has reached its end.

Comment: I am not sure how to make it work, i added this 
$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingLeftLimitReached: function (eventObj, data) {
        alert("Autoscroll left limit reached.");
    }
});


$("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingRightLimitReached: function (eventObj, data) {
        alert("Scrolled to element id " + data["golf"]);

    }
});

Comment: Can you show it in jsfiddle how this can be done. (only if its not too much to ask for).

Comment: Sadly, it seems that callbacks are bugged, according to the github issue tracker... I've edited my answer to reflect this new information.